# Fill input fields of the form with random values from an array (testing)

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, autofill

I have some long forms, and multi page forms too which I want fill automatically, by pressing a quick key. I want to do it with javascript/jquery, I've already found good plugins to do quick keys. What is the best approaching to fill input fields (name, phone, email etc...), with values from an array randomly? I didn't find any reasonable source on the web, or I just simply don't know what I'm exactly looking for, thats's why I can't find it :D Could you please give me some link, or anything?

Comment: how about using this library? http://chancejs.com/

Answer (score 0):

dork: `faker`

i use: `faker form jquery`

https://github.com/abhinavmsra/jQuery-faker

you can use that to create dummy like faker in PHP  did to the database.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that I would do by hand. My strategy would be to add a class to the input fields (we'll use `autofillMe`).

Now, with JavaScript, we can use `document.querySelector('.autofillMe')` to get references to all the elements we want to autofill. You can then just set the value of all these inputs!

Hope this helps!